# Can I change the active property using python?

Tags: python, scripting

When we click on property in blender this property becomes "active". By the active property I mean the property which receives input from keyboard.
I made an add-on with lots of properties of input, I want to change the active property using python so that when the user enters a value in a property and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> the next property becomes automatically active and waiting for input from user. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but why not be consistent with the rest of blender and have TAB both set the value as well as move to the next field?

Comment: I never knew that TAB moves to the next field, thank you!